# use variables in "document.Form1.checkbox.checked == true"

Tags: javascript, variables

in

```
    document.Form1.checkbox.checked == true
```

can i substitute Form1 and checkbox by javascript variables??

```
    var a= checkbox;
    var b= Form1;
    document.b.a.checked == true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var form = 'Form1';
var field = 'checkbox';

document[form][field].checked == true
```

Also you can give ID for that checkbox and then use it.

```
document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked == true
```

Comment: @nobodyshere that question is a bit specific and I don't think you've got the same problem. Please create new question and show your code there.

Comment: Don't worry I came across my own fix :)